# label and input box on the same line

Tags: html, css

I have a the following html:

```
<label>blah</label>
<input type=text ... />
```

I want the label to be on one row, and below it the input box.

currently it is on the same line, do I have to use a clear?

Comment: You can also just wrap both the label and the input in a div (w/ relative positioning) and then absolutely position the label and input to where you want them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do it with CSS:

label { clear: both; }

Comment: It doesn't work if you do not add `display:block` as well as @Mike Hall suggested in his answer

Answer (score 10):

You can put a css class or style that would change display to block:

```
<label style="display:block">blah</label>
<input type=text ... />
```

Answer (score 5):

```
<label>blah</label>
<br />
<input type=text ... />
```

Use a line break.

Answer (score 3):

```
<label for="fldAge">Age:</label>
<p>
<input type="text" name="Age" id="fldAge" />
</p>
```

This also causes the browser to render text associated with an input with a focus rectangle, and enables the user to focus the field by clicking anywhere in the associated text instead of just the input field control.

Answer (score 1):

You could throw in a breakline (`<br />`) between them or put each in its own div.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest way is to add a `<br>` after `</label>`.

Alternatively you could use div tags or a table with two rows.